# Java panel flipping horizontally

Tags: java, animation

I'm building a simple animation and the everything in my panel flips horizontally every few seconds.

[right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MWCr.png)

[flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zNHB.png)

All I'm doing is edge detection and then negating the speed in case of impact. I wrote the following code to prevent the character from flipping but it didn't help.

```
if (speed.x < 0) g.scale(1, -1);
```

thanks for the support guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused how you have this working since you are not showing any code. Here is how I would do it:

```
x += speedX;
y += speedY;
```

```
canvas.drawBitmap(pandaImage, x, y, null);
```

Look at this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6prI4ZB_rXI).